# Select an item from a databound list from a popup in windows phone

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am developing a windows phone App. I need to achieve the following functions.

1. Display a popup, which has list of values generated dynamically.
2. Should select one item and the selection should be highlighted.
3. Return the selected value to the calling page.

I am able to generate a list using data bound but not very sure about how to restrict to single selection. Also need help to highlight the selected item.

If not pop up what is the alternative method to achieve this without affecting the state of the calling page.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to demonstrate a basic understanding of the problem to post here. Please post what you have tried, your code and any errors you have received. You need to do this in order to receive a proper response.

Comment: I edited the question and included the code. Pls check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listpicker control in windows phone toolkit is an ideal control for the functionality i wanted.

To learn more about listpicker

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth